# R linear model function (lm) doesn't exclude predicted variable from predictors

Tags: r, lm

I have a dataframe where I want to predict all variables from the other variables, so I construct a loop like this one:

```
df = iris
df$Species <- NULL

mods = list()
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  mods[[i]] <- lm(df[, i] ~ ., df)
}
```

But, to my surprise, each variable appears as it's own predictor; even if I do:

```
mods = list()
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  mods[[i]] = lm(df[, i] ~ . - df[, i], df)
}
```

The same happens.

I know I can create the correct formula expression on the side with the proper names and so on, but I feel like this shouldn't be the desired behaviour for lm.

The question is: Am I missing something? Is there a reason why this function has such an uncomfortable behaviour? In case the answer to the previous questions is "no", shouldn't it be improved?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I thought it was implicit, but I have edited to make it clearer...

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know I can do that, but this is very awkward and I don't understand why the behaviour changes from giving an explicit name or accessing via column index.

Comment: df[, i] is just a vector, no index or name, so probably not that easy to check
for equivalence with values on the rhs of the formula without comparing values explicitly with those on the rhs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems expected and very much in line with how R operates to me. You are passing `df` into the `data` argument, but then referencing a different `df` in your formula (it is the same one, but a different object reference at this point.

In your first example, your `y` variable is not from `data`, it is from that other `df`. So therefore there is no `data` column and the `.` returns all.

In your second example, you are saying to include all variables from `data` but exclude a column from some other data frame `df`. So it excludes that column from `df` but still is left with all the columns from `data`.

I think this is what you are expecting:

```r
mods = list()
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  mods[[i]] = lm(df[, i] ~ ., df[, -i])
}
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense; shouldn't I get an error then when subtracting a column that wasn't there in the first place?

Comment: You are not subtracting a column that wan't there in the first place...despite pulling the same data from the same 'file' it is looking at two different instances of the data frame, two separate objects.

Comment: Yes, you can mix objects in `lm` as long as they have the same number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

It excludes names but that code does not use any.

```
df = iris
df$Species <- NULL

LM <- function(nm) {
  fo <- paste(nm, "~.")
  do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(df)))
}
Map(LM, names(df))
```

giving this 4 element list (only first shown):

```
$Sepal.Length

Call:
lm(formula = "Sepal.Length ~.", data = df)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width  
      1.8560        0.6508        0.7091       -0.5565  

## ..snip...
```